# Is there a way i can change the background of the navigation bar in html5 as the text flow up or as i scroll the text up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I would like to the navbar to be be stay static, and change the background as the text in the flow up or get scrolled up.
Here is the code.

Here is the html and css code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OWL7.png)

Comment: Please show us your effort,

Comment: Show your code. Thats what we read here. 
Your description in text is cool but on same token you yourself 
admit that things are going wrong. 
Only source code will reveal the errors. 
If you could update your post with your source code it would be 
highly productive in someone finding the bug. Also please read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

/* Add a staythere class. It should be added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */

```
.staythere {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript :

```
window.onscroll = function() 
{
     myFunction() /* Function to add staythere Class */
     /* Code to Change Background Color. Use any condition if necessary */
     document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // Here red is an Example

 };
```

/* Get the navbar */
    `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");`

/* Get the offset position of the navbar */
    `var fixedPos = navbar.offsetTop;`

// Add the "staythere" class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "staythere" when you leave the scroll position

```
function myFunction() {
if (window.pageYOffset >= fixedPos) {
navbar.addClass("staythere")
} else {
navbar.removeClass("staythere");
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, This makes some sense. I now get the clue. let me try it out,